# Cannot deserialize a 'BsonDocument' from BsonType 'Array'

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I'm getting this error at trying to parse a json string to BsonDocument.

The C# code is:

```
        string jsonText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"source.json");
        var document = BsonDocument.Parse(jsonText);
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collectionName");
        collection.InsertOne(document);
```

While last C# code works fine for a single document:

```
{
 "field1": 1,
 "field2": "value",
 "field3": "value",
 "field4": "value",
 "arr1": [
   {
    "arrField1": 1,
    "arrField2": "value"
   }
         ]
}
```

I'm getting the exception *Cannot deserialize a 'BsonDocument' from BsonType 'Array'* while parsing a json array document:

```
[
 {
  "field1": 1,
  "field2": "value",
  "field3": "value",
  "field4": "value",
  "arr1": [
    {
      "arrField1": 1,
      "arrField2": "value"
    }
          ]
 },
 {
  "field1": 2,
  "field2": "value",
  "field3": "value",
  "field4": "value",
  "arr1": [
    {
      "arrField1": 1,
      "arrField2": "value"
    }
          ]
  }
]
```

Any idea on how can I parse a json with multiple elements? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use `BsonArraySerializer`

```
using (var jsonReader = new JsonReader(text))
{
   var serializer = new BsonArraySerializer();
   var bsonArray = serializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(jsonReader));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer of @rnofenko
You can run over the array and insert document by document

```
BsonArray bsonArray;

using (var jsonReader = new JsonReader(text))
{
     var serializer = new BsonArraySerializer();
     bsonArray = serializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(jsonReader));
}

var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("SomeObject_Collection");

foreach (BsonValue bsonValue in bsonArray)
{
   var b = bsonValue.ToBsonDocument();
   await collection.InsertOneAsync(b);

}
```